# Why am I not allowed to use setOnClickListener in this situation?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

This makes no sense, I am given an error saying that setOnClickListener can't be applied to MainActivity. But i've made other projects where I've never encountered this problem. What's going on?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button));

    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Comment: What's the specific error you are getting? What is the type of the parameter to `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: I got it working now. See the last comment I left on @nicopasso 's post to see where i'm currently at.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to declare MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

and after that you have to override the onClick method in MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     //do something...
}
```

Comment: So I only have to do this for the MainActivity right?

Comment: You had to do this every time you want your activity became the listener of one of the view inside the activity itself

Answer (score 1):

As we can see you havn't implemented the `View.OnClickListener` on Main activity..
`this` will be used as `MainActivity` but the parameter that can be passed is `OnClickListener`

SideNote: Always try to typecast before you use, this greatly reduce the complications and sometimes takes you to mistakes you are doing.